# AngularJS accessing scope from $http.get function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, scope

I'm trying to change variable in scope from $http.get.then function, but it writes undefined. target.html loaded succesfully, I have tried and read response.

```
$scope.loaded_view = "before";
$scope.getView = function(name) {
        $http.get(chrome.extension.getURL("/views/" + name + ".html")).then(function(response, stat, xhr) {
            $scope.loaded_view = "after";
        });
        console.log($scope.loaded_view); //--> before
    }

$scope.getView('target');
console.log($scope.loaded_view); //—> before
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the getView function? Can you be more precise?

Comment: Due to the async nature of `get()` the `console.log()` is interpreted before the callback ( `then` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your `get request` **takes time to execute**

**`Javascript` executes from `top` to `bottom`**

You can think `$http` as a `timeout` service where it gives response after few mins. I created a `plunker` to demonstrate that

Check by moving `console.log` inside that `get function` and after the response has come

```
$scope.loaded_view = "before";
console.log('this is printed first(1)')
$scope.getView = function(name) {
        $http.get(chrome.extension.getURL("/views/" + name + ".html")).then(function(response, stat, xhr) {
            $scope.loaded_view = "after";
            console.log($scope.loaded_view); //--> after 
            console.log('this is printed third(3)')
        });
        console.log('this is printed second(2)')
    }

$scope.getView('target');
```

I added three `console.log()` to be more clearer and you can observe the sequence of those

**Sequence of console I added to make it clearer to you:**

1. this is printed first(1)
2. this is printed second(2)
3. this is printed third(3)

[**Plunker demonstrating the timeout delay**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QU4r05n9rQprwyL9Ltxh?p=info)

**Note:**

> Even though it is printing `before` in `console.log`, your `html` will
>   get updated with the `new value` **when ever the value changes** as
>   angular runs `digest cycle` when the scope value changes.

Comment: So if I will make get() “non async”, will it change $scope before console.log ?

Comment: Even though it is printing before in `console.log`, your `html` will get updated with the current value when ever the value changes as angular runs digest cycle when the scope value changes.

Comment: @user1938361 You can't make it non-async. That's the exact use of the $http.get(). You send a request to your server and in the meanwhile your JS-code can continue without being blocked while waiting for a reponse.

Comment: I can make it non async by sending Xhtmlrequest or JQuery. So without angularjs help

Comment: but the `non-async` lags in performance as we have to wait for the `response` before we do anything elser.